# iTuneConnect : App uploaded for test build but now showing anymore

Tags: swift, itunes

Currently I am developing an app and I want to send the client a test build , I had successfully archived the app and uploaded on AppStore ... Under the Activity section it was showing "processing" for about an hr or two , now its not showing neither anything nor the app been uploaded. Any idea what went wrong ? Did anybody experienced this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that something with your binary is wrong.

You would expect to get notified about that issue in the **Activity** tab but it seems that (currently) you can only find the invalid build in the **App Store** tab when selecting a new build.

Also you should have received an email (iTunes Connect account) describing the issue.

Comment: since its my office account I can not see the mail right now but I guess this might be the issue . thank you for your suggestion .

Comment: ran into the problem yesterday. I'm glad if this fixes the issue for you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes ,Some times it take time .
In my case i have wait for 4 hour then it will reflect on itunes connect account.[image]

or you can check build status in a activity .
Please check linked image for references

Comment: my problem was , it was showing "processing" under "activity" but later it was gone ! app was not uploaded either . I have uploaded app before but never had this before .

Comment: This types of problems comes when APPLE server is low .  

My colleague also faced same problem .  

He try for second time his " app uploaded successfully" .

Comment: might be, coz it says "We are currently experiencing processing issues. Build processing may be delayed" . I have uploaded the app 3 times now since yesterday, still couldn't even upload it on iTuneConnect either .

Answer (score -1):

I got an email from apple saying "This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data" . I then added some **string** on **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** and uploaded it , it worked like a charm .